# fix json data formatting issues in several files using bash

Tags: json, bash

I'm using an app-store-scraper (https://github.com/facundoolano/app-store-scraper/) to pull reviews and read them using python. The problem is that the output of the app isn't quite in json format, so the data needs some fixing.

Here is the node.js code that produces the output:

```
var store = require('app-store-scraper');

store.reviews({
  id: 300238550,
  sort: store.sort.HELPFUL,
  page: 1
})
.then(console.log)
.catch(console.log);
```

Here's a sample record from the output:

```
  {
id: '123456789',
userName: 'user123',
userUrl: 'https://itunes.apple.com/us/reviews/id1234567',
version: '150.71.0',
score: 1,
title: 'Difficulties and errors signing up',
text: 'The site asks you to put all your information and to link all your bank accounts and financial accounts accounts using your passwords.  \n' +
      'Multiple times reports errors.  "Sorry, our site is not working at this time".   For me, a waist of my time.',
url: 'https://itunes.apple.com/us/review?id=11111111111'
  },
```

where the "text" value is being printed on two separate lines in the output file.

I'm using pandas.read_json, which gives a lot of errors when trying to read the files as-is. I think the data should be in the format as follows:

```
  {
"id": "123456789",
"userName": "user123",
"userUrl": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/reviews/id1234567",
"version": "150.71.0",
"score": 1,
"title": "Difficulties and errors signing up",
"text": "The site asks you to put all your information and to link all your bank accounts and financial accounts accounts using your passwords. Multiple times reports errors.  'Sorry, our site is not working at this time'.   For me, a waist of my time.",
"url": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/review?id=11111111111"
  },
```

The problems are:

1. Quotations are missing around the key values.
2. Quotations are missing around strings. A challenge here is that some strings contain apostrophes and quotations as well.
   2a. Some strings have multiple occurrences of \n + which splits the strings into multiple pieces on separate lines.

I'm working on macOS Sonoma 14.0, so am using BASH. Here's my solution that fixes problem 1:

```
find . -name '*.json' | xargs awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=":"} 
{
    if (NF > 1) {
        gsub(/^ *| *$/, "", $1);  # Trim leading and trailing spaces
        $1 = "\"" $1 "\"";
        print $0;
        next;
    }
    print;
}' >> output.txt
```

Problem 2 is a little more complicated, so I would greatly appreciate any help devising a fix for it. I'm not concerned with quotations within the overall text (like the 'Sorry ...time' portion in the example), so if it's easier to remove all apostrophes and quotations that are within the string, that works for me as long as the text ends up in one continuous string wrapped in quotations.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks to share the code you use in javascript to generate this output. The way to go should be to use `JSON` built-in module: `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: Just added the code to execute the app.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var store = require('app-store-scraper');

var raw = store.reviews({
  id: 300238550,
  sort: store.sort.HELPFUL,
  page: 1
});
var json = JSON.parse(raw);
console.log(JSON.stringify(json, null, 4));
```

Comment: undefined:1
[object Promise]
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'o', "[object Promise]" is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/kb/app_v2.js:16:17)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Comment: I tested your code and above is the error message. I checked the data using the original script to see if the error was related to a string "Promise" perhaps, but this word wasn't in the data. I'm not sure how to interpret this error.

Comment: I don't think you need `JSON.parse()`, just changing the `console.log()` part to use `JSON.stringify()` should be sufficient.

Comment: I don't know node.js, so I've tried a couple of different variations. 

// Left everything the same, except removed JSON.parse:
var store = require('app-store-scraper');

var raw = store.reviews({
  id: 300238550,
  sort: store.sort.HELPFUL,
  page: 1
});
var json = raw;
console.log(JSON.stringify(json, null, 4));

Results in an empty file.

Comment: Then I tried keeping only the json argument of JSON.stringify:

var store = require('app-store-scraper');

var raw = store.reviews({
  id: 300238550,
  sort: store.sort.HELPFUL,
  page: 1
});
var json = raw;
console.log(JSON.stringify(json));

This results in an empty file also.

Comment: Then I tried the original script substituting console.log with JSON.stringify:

var store = require('app-store-scraper');

store.reviews({
    id: 300238550,
    sort: store.sort.HELPFUL,
    page: 1
  })
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(JSON.stringify);

The output was the same as with console.log.

Answer (score 0):

Post-processing solution in [TXR](https://nongnu.org.txr):

```
@(do (defun esc-quote (str) (regsub "\"" "\\\"" str)))
@(repeat :gap 0)
@  (cases)
@prop: '@raw0'@{comma /,?/}
@    (bind out `    "@prop" : "@(esc-quote raw0)"@comma`)
@  (or)
@prop: '@raw0' +
@    (collect :vars (rawn))
 '@rawn' +
@    (last)
 '@rawl'@{comma /,?/}
@    (end)
@    (bind out `    "@prop" : "@(esc-quote (join raw0 rawn rawl))"@comma`)
@  (or)
@prop: @val
@    (bind out `    "@prop" : @val`)
@  (or)
@out
@  (end)
@  (do (put-line out))
@(end)
```

```
$ txr data.txr data
  {
    "id" : "123456789",
    "userName" : "user123",
    "userUrl" : "https://itunes.apple.com/us/reviews/id1234567",
    "version" : "150.71.0",
    "score" : 1,
    "title" : "Difficulties and errors signing up",
    "text" : "The site asks you to put all your information and to link all your bank accounts and financial accounts accounts using your passwords.  \nMultiple times reports errors.  \"Sorry, our site is not working at this time\".   For me, a waist of my time.",
    "url" : "https://itunes.apple.com/us/review?id=11111111111"
  },
```

Colorized by Vim:

[image: Colorized by Vim]

Comment: Thanks for your attempt. Never heard of txr before. Here is the error message your code gives when applying the script to a full file. For clarity, here is the command line execution:

txr mod.txr mint_critical_2.json >> achk.txt

Your code was copied/pasted directly to mod.txr.

Error:

mod.txr:18: syntax error
mod.txr:19: newline expected after directive
mod.txr:19: syntax error

Comment: I can reproduce the issue; it is a bad copy and paste. The terminal copied spaces at the ends of line. My original code, which looks like the image, works fine. I will redo the copy and paste.

Comment: Here's the error message from transcribing the code in the screenshot:
mod.txr:21: syntax error

Here's the error from copy/paste of the updated code:
mod.txr:21: syntax error

Comment: That doesn't repro for me here. If I copy and paste the code shown in the question, and put it into a file, it's accepted without syntax errors. `diff` shows no differences between that and my original.

Comment: It works with TXR versions as far back as 279. Before that, `regsub` required a regex argument; if I change to `(regsub #/"/ "\\\"" str)`, it works with 254.  254 introduced `join`. If I replace `join` with `append`,  it works with TXR 91 binaries  from July 2014 (built on Ubuntu 11!)

Comment: What platform are you using? Did you build TXR yourself?

Comment: I'm on macOS Sonoma 14.0, txr version 291, installed via homebrew. When I run your code against the single record above, here's the error message: 
mod.txr: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
mod.txr: line 1: `@(do (defun esc-quote (str) (regsub "\"" "\\\"" str)))'

Comment: This is not the first time I've received reports of weird/unreliable behavior with Homebrew builds of TXR.  The [Homebrew build formula for TXR](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/txr) does not run `make tests`. :(

Comment: I just built TXR 291 on an M1 mac running macOS 12.6. Almost all `make tests` pass except some `chmod` tests.  This is the file `txr-291-OSX-12.6-M1.tar.Z` , in  [this download directory](https://www.kylheku.com/txr-downloads/txr-291/).  SHA-256 sum is in the `CHECKSUMS` file.  It's dynamically linked to `libffi`, which is not included.

Comment: ... changed it to statically linked `libz` and `libffi`. Only dynamic dep is `https://www.zlib.net/zlib-1.3.tar.gz`.

Comment: I tried the same code on a pc and it didn't work either, so I had to come up with a different method.

Comment: It [works for me](https://i.imgur.com/RX6knBt.png) on a Windows 11 laptop, using TXR 291 (64 bit), on the sample data given in the question. Maybe the question needs a more representative sample of data.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution that was very close using bash, but due to some unknown character types, the "text" string would never end up in the exact json format. To resolve the issue, I thought why haven't any of the other users of this app had the same issues; i.e. why weren't more people posting about this problem. Turns out that the call to the app that I pulled from the README.txt undid the json formatting. After some testing, here is complete solution to using this app for pulling reviews:

```
var store = require('app-store-scraper');
var fs = require('fs');

// Dictionary to map sort keys to desired filename parts
const sortNameMapping = {
    'RECENT': 'recent',
    'HELPFUL': 'helpful',
    'FAVORITE': 'favorite',
    'CRITICAL': 'critical'
};

async function fetchReviews(appId, appName, sortKey, pageNum) {
  const reviews = await store.reviews({
    id: appId,
    sort: store.sort[sortKey],  // Access the sort method using store.sort[sortKey]
    page: pageNum
  });
  
  // Use the mapping to get the correct part for the filename
  const sortName = sortNameMapping[sortKey];

  // Construct the filename using the app name, sort name, and page number
  const fileName = `${appName.toLowerCase()}_${sortName}_${pageNum}.json`;

  // Write reviews to the constructed filename
  fs.writeFileSync(fileName, JSON.stringify(reviews, null, 2), 'utf-8');
}

// Dictionary of app names and their IDs
const appIds = {
  mint: 300238550,
  rocket: 1130616675,
  nerd: 1174471607,
  ynab: 1010865877
};

// Array of sort keys
const sortKeys = ['RECENT', 'HELPFUL', 'FAVORITE', 'CRITICAL'];

// Array of page numbers
const pageNumbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

// Loop over each combination of id, sort key, and page number
for (let appName in appIds) {
  for (let sortKey of sortKeys) {
    for (let pageNum of pageNumbers) {
      fetchReviews(appIds[appName], appName, sortKey, pageNum);
    }
  }
}
```

It's set up to create one file per app, per filter type, per page number. The example above generates 40 json files per app, though all of the records may not be unique.